# AlertDialog changes the app background to black, want to maintain last background

Tags: flutter, bluetooth-lowenergy

I have this widget:

```
class DeviceNotRecognizedDialog extends StatelessWidget {
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return AlertDialog(
      backgroundColor: Colors.redAccent,
      title: Text('Dispositivo No Reconocido'),
      content: Text(
          'El dispositivo seleccionado no cumple con las normas de comunicacion establecidas para esta aplicación'
      ),
      actions: [
        TextButton(
            child: Text('OK'),
            onPressed: () => Navigator.pop(context),
        )
      ],
    );

  }
}
```

Nested in this part of the code for a Bluetooth app:

```
            StreamBuilder<List<ScanResult>>(
                stream: FlutterBlue.instance.scanResults,
                initialData: [],
                builder: (c, snapshot) => Column(   //Filter bl device nam
                  children: snapshot.data!
                      .where((r) => DeepCollectionEquality().equals(r.advertisementData.manufacturerData, oakTecManufacturer)).toList().map(
                        (r) => ScanResultTile(
                          result: r,
                          onTap: () => Navigator.of(context)
                              .push(MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) {
                            if(r.advertisementData.serviceData.length == 1){
                              r.device.connect();
                              return DeviceScreen(device: r.device,program: PROGRAM_SELECTED); //conecta con el dispositivo y habre device screen
                            }
                            else {
                              return DeviceNotRecognizedDialog();
                            }

                          })),
                        ),
                      )
                      .toList(),
                ),
              )
```

The app look like this without pressing the button:

[image: 1]

And when I pressed the button it looks like this:

[image: 2]

I want it to look something like this:

[image: 3]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The thing is you're not actually creating a Dialog, you're pushing into the stack of navigation the widget `DeviceScreen` or `DeviceNotRecognizedDialog` depending your data, what you need to do is do your logic first and then decide if you need to push or open dialog:

```
onTap: () async {
  if(r.advertisementData.serviceData.length == 1) {
     r.device.connect(); /// Tal vez deberías intentar conectar en el otro widget y no aqui
     Navigator.of(context).push(
       MaterialPageRoute(builder: (_) => return DeviceScreen(device: r.device,program: PROGRAM_SELECTED),
     ); //conecta con el dispositivo y abre device screen
  } else {
    showDialog(
      context: context,
      barrierDismissible: true,
      barrierColor: Colors.transparent, /// Aqui es donde escoges el color de fondo detras del dialogo
      builder: (_)  => DeviceNotRecognizedDialog()
    );        
  }
}
```